# update statement from inside cursor

Tags: mysql, cursor

I am using a cursor using a select on one table.

From inside the cursor loop, I want to update **another** table based on of the values from the current cursor row.

[This page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursor-restrictions.html) states that updates are not allowed, but I get the feeling it is only for the tables that are part of initial cursor SELECT. But for other tables which are not part of the initial cursor SELECT, can we not update them also?

Comment: It should be no problem at all to update *tables* - you just cannot update `CURRENT` (ie the presently selected record in the cursor result).  This is because MySQL cursors are not updateable aka read-only.  I think they stress this limitation because updateable cursors is a feature many other databases do have.

Comment: Ok. this is confirmed to be correct.